# Takewhile lambda function not recognizing string

Tags: python, comments, python-itertools

So I have a comment section at the start of my file. What I want is for the line that starts '# Description: ' to be pulled. But for some reason I don't understand, it isn't working.
Entering '#' gets what I expect, as does '# NOTE', but '# Description: ' and even '# D' seems to return nothing. Can someone help me understand this?

Here's my file's comment section:

```
# NOTE: successive whitespace characters treated as single delimiter
# NOTE: all lines beginning with '#' treated as comments
# NOTE: Description must come after '# Description: ' to be recognized
#
# Description: High dispersion optics with O-16 (4+) at 6 MeV/nucleon. Provided by <first, last> on <datetime>.
#
#
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from itertools import takewhile
with open(pathname, 'r') as fobj:
    # takewhile returns an iterator over all the lines
    # that start with the comment string
    headiter = takewhile(lambda s: s.startswith('# Description: '), fobj)
    description = list(headiter)
```

Comment: It's as if the function is only working for the first '# NOTE:' lines, and nothing after. Though '#' returns the description line within the list, '# ' does not. It doesn't seem to matter what string I replace 'Description' with.

Comment: When deleting the blank comment line between the third NOTE line and the Description line, using string '# ' does return the description line too, though using '# D' or '# Description: ' still doesn't. I still don't get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takewhile` will **keep** the elements from the iterator until the condition is False. In your case, the condition is False in the beginning and only becomes True on the third line.

You want to use **`dropwhile`** and `next`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
with open(pathname, 'r') as fobj:
    # dropping lines until they don't start with "# Description:"
    headiter = dropwhile(lambda s: not s.startswith('# Description: '), fobj)
    # getting next element
    description = next(headiter)
```

output:

```
'# Description: High dispersion optics with O-16 (4+) at 6 MeV/nucleon. Provided by <first, last> on <datetime>.'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! I don't quite understand what next() is doing though. Does it simply take the next item, in this case, the first of the list?

Comment: @DanielCrisp `next` is taking the next element in an iterable, try to run it once more and you'll get the line after, etc. until the iterator is exhausted, at which point it returns a `StopIteration` exception

Comment: Great, that makes sense. thanks again, I really appreciate it!